# Dividir un arreglo en subarreglos que contienen la cantidad de datos pasada como parámetro

Tags: javascript

La función `pedazos` recibe un arreglo llamado `array` y un numero entero llamado `cantidad`. Esta debe separar el array recibido en `N` subarreglos que tengan como máximo el numero recibido en cantidad de elementos.

Por ejemplo:

```
pedazos([1,2,3,4,5], 2) -> retorna [[1,2], [3,4], [5]);

pedazos([1,2,3,4,5], 4) -> retorna [[1,2,3,4], [5]); 

pedazos{[1,2],4) -> retorna [[1,2]];
```

No he llegado a concretar un intento debido a que no se me ocurre como realizarlo. Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
function pedazos(array, cantidad) {
      let arregloMain = []
      let divisor = cantidad;
      let base = 0;
      let arreglo = array.map(function(valores){
          array.slice(base, divisor);
      })
      return arregloMain
}
```

Esta fue la única idea que tuve durante el día pero esta incompleta, no se como realizar la idea que tengo en mi cabeza, esa idea era ir aumentando en dos la base y el divisor cada vez que se realizara una acción, pero la idea quedo ahi, se que no es correcta y no se me ocurre nada mas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código se acerca bastante a la solución, solo que debes iterar con un incremento igual a la variable cantidad e ir agregando los subarreglos a resultado. Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```js
function pedazos(array, cantidad) {
    var resultado = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += cantidad) {
        resultado.push(array.slice(i, i + cantidad));
    }
    return resultado;
}

// Pruebas
console.log(pedazos([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4)) // [[1,2,3,4],[5]]
console.log(pedazos([1, 2], 4))          // [[1,2]]
```

Comment: gracias, aun no conozco los limites de los bucles.